# Delete rows in database where id not found in a filtered query in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

I'd like to remove rows in my database where an ID is not found amongst ID's from a filtered query. In layman's term, "Delete rows if the row's ID is not amongst ID's sourced from a query that kept unique users by name".

For example, I would like to clear out users in my database with duplicate names:

```py
from project.models import db, User

query = User.query.group_by(User.name)
User.query.filter(** filter out User.id not found in `query.id` **).delete()
db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I came to a working solution after some digging:

```py
from project.models import db, User

# Filter id's where `User.name` is unique
query = User.query.with_entities(User.id).group_by(User.name)
del_query = User.__table__.delete().where(User.id.not_in(query))

# Delete posts with non-unique names
db.session.execute(del_query)
db.session.commit()
```

This solution does not filter iteratively using `User.query.group_by(User.name).all()`, which could introduce time and memory issues if your database is large.

Answer (score 0):

You can call filter multiple times on same query object.

```
query = User.query.group_by(User.name).all()
delete_query = db.session.query()
for user in query:
    delete_query = delete_query.filter(User.id != user.id)
delete_query.delete()
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Note that query execution is not happening unless in certain conditions, so doing this will only execute one query.